# Is it possible to use google app engine map in website

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

I need to book homes. I need to show google map then agent place information of home on map using marker. When user come on web site they saw property listing on map. Is it possible to use google app engine? Can I use PHP or I need to use java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google maps with google app engine.

Here is a relevant link: http://wtp2.appspot.com/AppEngineMapDemo.htm

> This demo uses the Google AppEngine as a data store for users to pin photos on a map with server side scripting in Python.

It also includes source.

You cannot use PHP (yet) on Google App Engine, but you can use Java, Go and Python.

Here are some geo-related samples: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/wiki/GoogleAppEngineSamples